# Weak limit and strong limit

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $x_n \overbrace{\rightarrow}^w x$ and $x_n \overbrace{\rightarrow}^s z$ can we then say that $x = z$?
My try:

$$\| x- z\| = \sup_{\ell \leq 1} |\ell(x-z)| = \sup_{\ell \leq 1} |\ell x -\ell z| \leq \epsilon$$

Where $\ell$ is a continuous functional in $X'$
Is this correct? is there any easier way?
Thanks
Btw if this already is correct, should I delete the post or 
what do I do?

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$? And in the supremum, you should write you take it over the linear continuous functionals of norm $\leqslant 1$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary small number? Will the choice of $\ell$ affect my result?

Comment: No problem as the norm is bounded by $1$. But the las inequality deserves an additional step introducing the sequence $\{x_n\}$ (hence you don't really need $\varepsilon$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If $ x_{n} \to z $ strongly, then $ x_{n} \to z $ weakly also. Since the weak topology is Hausdorff, we have uniqueness of the limit. Therefore, $ z = x $.

Comment: the strong topology is finer than the weak

Comment: why is weak topology hausdorff?

Comment: you can use Hahn–Banach (second geometric form) to prove that weak topology is hausdorff

Answer (score 6):

If $x_n\to x$ weakly and $x_n\to z$ weakly, it follows that  $f(x)=f(z)$ for any $f\in X^{*}$. Hence $f(x-z)=0$ for any $f\in X^{*}$. An immediate application of Hahn-Banach implies $x=z$. Indeed, otherwise we can build a functional $g_0$ on span$\{x-z\}$ such that $g_0(x-z)=1$, and use Hahn-Banach extend it to a functional $g$ on $X$. For this $g\in X^{*}$ we would have $g(x-z)=1$.

Comment: this is a nice soln