# Weak limit of disjoint normalized sequence in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> I want to prove that the weak limit of a disjoint normalized (pairwise disjoint supports, elements of norm $1$) sequence $(f_n)$ in $L^p$ for $p >1$ is zero ?
>
> I started with the measure of the support of each function $f_n$ , but is it true that it goes to zero ?

Comment: what is a *disjoint normalized* sequence?

Comment: @ Emanuele it means that each function in this sequence has norm 1 and each two functions have disjoint supports

Comment: Do you know that every bounded sequence in $L_p$ with $1<p<\infty$ has a weakly convergent subsequence?

Comment: @ Jonas .. beacause Lp spaces are reflexive !

Comment: Here is a suggested approach with disclaimer that I've not thought through it well:  Try to show that if $(g_n)$ converges weakly to $g$ and $(g_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$, then $g=0$ a.e.  Because every bounded sequence in $L_p$ with $1<p<\infty$ has a weakly convergent subsequence, this implies that every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a subsequence that converges weakly to $0$.  In any topological space, given a sequence $(x_n)$, if there exists $x$ such that every subsequence of $(x_n)$ has a subsequence that converges to $x$, then $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

Comment: @ Jonas I'll try.. thanx

Comment: @ Jonas we know that each subsequence of (f_n) has a subsequence which converges to zero weakly, since Lp is reflixive and (f_n) is a basic sequence in it ! but can you give me a reference or a proof for the claim : In any topological space, given a sequence (x_n), if there exists x such that every subsequence of (x_n) has a subsequence that converges to x, then (x_n) converges to x.

Comment: @ValAnderson:  Suppose that $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$.  Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\{n:x_n\not\in U\}$ is infinite.  The subsequence of all terms not in $U$ has no subsequence converging to $x$.

Comment: @Val: If you type "@Jonas" instead of "@ Jonas", then I will receive notification of your comment.  I do not receive notification when there is a space between `@` and my name.

Comment: @Jonas thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_j$ be the support of $f_j$, $S:=\bigcup_jS_j$ and $q$ the conjugate exponent of $p$ (that is $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$). Then for each $g\in L^q$ and each $n_0$, we have 
$$\int f_n\cdot  \operatorname{sgn}(f)|g|\chi_{S_{n_0}}\to \int |f|\cdot|g|\chi_{n_0}$$ 
as $n\to +\infty$. But the LHS is $0$ when $n>n_0$ so for each $n_0$, $f\chi_{S_{n_0}}=0$ hence $f\chi_S=0$.

As $\{f_n\chi_S\}=\{f_n\}$, this sequence converges weakly to both $f$ and $f\chi_S=0$, and [a weak limit is unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267086/weak-limit-and-strong-limit/267087#), so we can conclude.

Comment: Is $f$ the weak limit of a subsequence of the bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in $L_p$?

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove it is by using the following 2 facts 1- a normalized disjoint sequence in $Lp$ is basic, and  2- every basic sequence in reflexive space $X$ is weakly null !